# How the new Omnitrix watch connected to the old Ultimatrix plot?

Tags: plot-explanation, continuity, ben-10, ben-10-omniverse

In the Ben 10 Omniverse there are so many continuity issues i observed But the main issue is with his new watch, Is there anything mention in any episode which i have missed?

I mean how can this new watch can exists with the old Ultimatrix plot.

Is there any official clarification about it ?

Comment: [Relevant Meta Discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/734/should-we-allow-jumping-the-shark-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last episode of "Ben 10: Ultimate Alien", Azmuth takes the Ultimatrix back from Ben and gives him the new improved Omnitrix Ben's wearing in "Ben 10: Omniverse".

Comment: May be i missed that seen, also found it on wiki after your answer here -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ben_10:_Ultimate_Alien_episodes

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, although this version of an omnitrix exists in the final ep. of B10:UA, the Ben of the future of B10:UA who had knowledge of the events involving the temporal villian Eon is seen only using an Ultramatrix of the same design as the Ben of the present. While it is possible Ben simple returned to using the more combat oriented model in the future no such explination has been offered. However, concidering the term 'omniverse' indicates multiple universes are involved, and the fact that the personality of this Ben is definitively different from that of B10:AF&UA, it is more likely this is yet another Ben Tennyson who may at some later date interact with the B10:AF&UA universe.  Unfortunately, the B10 series are notorious for unexplained changes to continuity.